# `fin.get(ch);` reads last character twice while `ch=fin.get();` not inside `while(!fin.eof())` loop why?

Tags: c++, get, file-handling, ifstream, eof

**vicky.txt file**

```
I was born in Hupari.
```

**Code -1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("vicky.txt", std::ios::in);

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.get(ch);
        std::cout<<ch;
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
I was born in Hupari..
```

**Code -2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("vicky.txt", std::ios::in);

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        ch=fin.get();
        std::cout<<ch;
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
I was born in Hupari.
```

Why while using `fin.get(ch)` it reads last character twice. On other hand `ch=fin.get()` reads correctly means reads last character one time only.

By the way also tell return type of `fin.get(ch)` ? and return type of `fin.get()` is `char` right ?

Comment: Neither are correct.  Neither are checking for EOF for the `fin.get`. Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/4641116

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both versions are wrong. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) for more details on how to correctly code reading loops.

---

Now, to the explanation what happens. The first version uses second overload of [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). This method leaves its argument unchanged if read fails (e.g. when end of file is reached) and sets flag. Thus, you print the last read character once again.

The second version uses first overload of [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). Because this version must return a character and cannot leave it unchanged like the other versions, it returns an `int` to be able to return special value `EOF` (which must not represent any valid character). `EOF` is typically equal to `-1` (as `int`). Then, you implicitly cast it to `char`, which would make it equal to `255` (or keep it as `-1`, but 8 bits). You then print it. Depending on the code page used by the terminal, it could be ÿ char, non-breaking space or something else. Possibly, you have that non-breaking space character printed, or some other invisible or unprintable character.

Comment: what is return type of `fin.get(ch)` ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane The return value is `fin`, i.e. the same stream that you called the method on. This allows you to chain calls. For example, chain like this - `fin.get(ch).eof()` would let you check `eof` value after read. Or, the better version, `if(fin.get(ch))` will only run if the read was successful.